# Fill column values based on values of a column in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes:

```
DataFrame 1:
Category,Criterion,Value1
Cat1,Crit1,0.1
Cat2,Crit2,0.2
Cat3,Crit3,0.15
Cat3,Crit4,0.22
Cat4,Crit5,0.3
Cat4,Crit6,0.3

Dataframe2:
Category,Value2
Cat1,0.23
Cat2,0.31
Cat3,0.12
Cat4,0.11
```

What I want to do, is to add a column at Dataframe 1 with the values of Dataframe 2. Thus, get the following dataframe:

```
Category,Criterion,Value1,Value2
Cat1,Crit1,0.1,0.23
Cat2,Crit2,0.2,0.31
Cat3,Crit3,0.15,0.12
Cat3,Crit4,0.22,0.12
Cat4,Crit5,0.3,0.11
Cat4,Crit6,0.3,0.11
```

Thanks

Comment: try `dplyr::left_join(DataFrame1, DataFrame2, by = "Category")`

Comment: `merge(df1,df2, all = TRUE)`